# No me reconoce las reglas del .htacces en mi cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

Tengo en mi host un sistema en el cual tengo unas reglas en .htaccess la cuales son las url amigables, que no son necesarios las extenciones .php y .html y al momento de redirigir el login no me encuentra el archivo

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://midominio/Error_404/

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: ¿Has hecho un reload al servicio de apache para que vuelva a leer los ficheros de configuracion?

Comment: Realmente no pero lo único que e hecho es crear nuevas reglas

Comment: has intentado darle un reset al servicio de apache,etc para tome las nuevas especificaciones?

Comment: Realmente no, voy a probar